# Div's Height and Width issue?

Tags: html, css

is it is necessary to give the height and width to the div when we can manage it without these two portieres.
for example we have a div which contain and img tag and the div can automatically takes the specific height and with according to the image size. and if we are wanted to increase its height or width we can manage it using padding property?

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px;">

<img src="" >

</div>
```

we can manage it as

```
<div style="padding:10px;">

<img src="" >

</div>
```

Comment: It depends on your page's layout... If you don't need to define the dimensions of the container div, then don't

Comment: @Mehar check this question [Why does CSS padding increase size of element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767010/why-does-css-padding-increase-size-of-element)

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis what if i define the container width to 960px and don't give the height and width to the inner div's ?

Answer (score 0):

Padding should do the trick, if you want a bit of space around the image, you can test ow much size there is, or how it looks by adding a colour to the background `background-color:#999999` just so you can see how it looks, then if you want to pad one side but not the other use:

```
padding-top-left:10px;
//or
padding-bottom-right:10px;
```

.... ect

or if you want it to be really secific, set the image size then set the div size around that, and add padding, that way it is exactly what you want