# Why setting padding makes two horizontal div vertical?

Tags: html, css

If i remove padding from below code two vertical div became horizontal, Why this is happening because as far as i know padding affects internal spacing. I am expecting two horizontally aligned divs from below code

```html
<style>
#wrapper {
width:100%;
margin : 0;
}

#first-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
float : left ;
padding: 10px;
background-color: green;
color: white;
}

#second-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
float : left ;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="first-div" >
            First  div content here...
        </div> 
        <div id="second-div" >
            Second div content here...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does CSS padding increase size of element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767010/why-does-css-padding-increase-size-of-element)

Comment: Solution [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="first-div" >
                First  div content here...
            </div>
            <div id="second-div" >
                Second div content here...
            </div>
        </div>
<style>
#wrapper {
width:100%;
margin : 0;
}

#first-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
float : right ;
padding: 10px;
background-color: green;
color: white;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#second-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
float : right ;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;

}
</style>
```

You should said your div box-sizing as border-box
than it take padding after border internally.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are keeping the `width` at 50% and the extra padding is added additionally to that width making the element collapse to a new line (*due to `float: left`*)

This should not happen if you apply [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to each div. This ensures that padding is included within the width of the element

Answer (score 0):

try to use display flex instead float:

```
#wrapper {
width:100%;
margin : 0;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: column;
}

#first-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
background-color: green;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
}

#second-div {
width:50%;
margin : 0;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
}
```